# React native flatlist item shifting right

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to show only 3 items on screen and when scroolling using animatin flatlist but as it progresses the numbers shift to the right.How can i fix?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuBkH.png)

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  Platform,
  Dimensions,
  Animated,
  } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: You haven’t shared your code properly

Comment: i can not add code,

Comment: Why not? Just press edit and then add the code where you have a problem. No one can help you if you don’t show what you tried. What tutorial are you following?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve you functionality by using `react-native-snap-carousel`
instead of using Flatlist